# Model relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

The problem is that I add the relationships to my models and PHPstorm says that the function rooms is a 'Unused element' and the relation doe snot work.

I already went through the documentation of laravel and searched google for a solutions

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Type extends Model
{
    public function rooms()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Room');
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Room extends Model
{
    public function type(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\room');
    }
}
```

The relation should give the room numbers on my view and currently it is blank

Answer (score 3):

It's Seems you mentioned the wrong relationship in the type method.

```
public function type(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Type');
}
```

Comment: So give me more information. I need your code in your controller.